# angular injecting $element into a controller works in most places but not one

Tags: angularjs, element

injecting $scope and $element into a controller works in most places in my project, but in one it doesn't. There doesn't seem to be any reason that it shouldn't work in this instance. removing it, the rest of the controller works OK, but in this particular controller, if injected, I get the following console error: angular.js:10072 [unknownService-unhandledError]  An unhandled error has occurred: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element

```
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$element', 'MyApp', controller]);

function controller($scope, $element, myApp) {
```

Googling for it, there seem to be a few reports of this, but no real answer, I can work around it, just want to understand it.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet? Hard to see what is going on here.

Comment: Is controllerId a string variable or the controller name?  If controller name, it needs to be in quotes.  What is 'MyApp'  that you are injecting into the controller?  Also, I can't help but ask ... why are you injecting $element into controller code?  Hopefully not for DOM manipulation.

Comment: The question is very unclear!

Comment: @jbrown not DOM manipulation: checking to see if an element is visible before getting data from a server. the point is it doesn't matter what is in the controller, Angular is throwing the exception on the injection. It's hardly unknown, when I googled, there were a number of reports of the same issue. MyApp is just an example other service, it doesn't matter what it is. I've not used the customer code but psuedo code instead to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @JeffDavies - How do you expect us to help you if you share pseudo code with issues in it and then say those things don't matter?  In an attempt to help you I created a plunk and put the controller name in quotes and removed the reference to MyApp then the app loads with no errors to the console.  Obviously a wasted effort since that's not your code anyhow.  As you can see from other comments, the general consensus is that you aren't doing much to help us help you.

Comment: apologies jbrown. As mentioned I've used the same code in a great many places, in one controller this doesn't work. I was wondering if someone else had encountered the issue. As mentioned, it's raised by a number of people if you google for the error code, but with no satisfactory solution. Please, if you haven't encountered the issue, I suggest you don't waste time on it. I thought I was pretty specific about this in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The `$compile` service injects `$element` into controllers as a local, `ngRoute` does not.

### From the `$compile` Docs:

> ### controller
>
> Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and can be accessed by other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the **following locals**:
>
> - `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element
> - `$element` - Current element
> - `$attrs` - Current attributes object for the element
> - `$transclude` - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope:

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

### From the `ngRoute` Docs:

> ### `locals`
>
> A map of locals which is used by [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service for
>          controller instantiation. The `locals` contain
>          the resolved values of the `resolve` map. Additionally the `locals` also contain:
>
> - `$scope` - The current route scope.
> - `$template` - The current route template HTML.
>
> The `locals` will be assigned to the route scope's `$resolve` property. You can override
>           the property name, using `resolveAs` in the route definition. See
>           [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for more info.

-- [AngularJS ngRoute $route API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#current)